# pass a class to set_error_handler

Tags: php, error-handling

Is there a way to set an error handler that takes a callback function as a static function? like so:

```
set_error_handler(Errors::errorHandler());
```

I am not using OO PHP, so I don't want to create a function after my procedural code. I would rather prefer that the error be passed to a class function.

Comment: You're _not_ using OO PHP, so you'd prefer to use a class function? How does that work?

Comment: You'll want to read up on the various flavors of [PHP Callables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For static methods:

`set_error_handler(array('CallbackClass', 'StaticMethod'));`

For non-static methods:

```
$obj = new CallbackClass();
set_error_handler(array($obj, 'Method'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the argument can be any [callable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php):

```
set_error_handler(array('Errors', 'errorHandler'));
```

Comment: In your example, what are 'Errors' and 'errorHandler' for?

Comment: They're the values **you gave us**. It's the class, and the static class method.